# how to add online image in epub3 file?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ibooks, epub3

I want to include online images in my EPUB3 file but when i validate it it shows me error "Only audio and video remote resources are permitted".when i include it using javascript it is working fine in Android e reader but images are not shown in iBooks.

Answer (score 2):

you probably need to save or download images into your android project folder and should access the images. refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510721/how-to-get-the-images-of-epub-book-in-android) for reference