# How to read image file from ePub file in android

Tags: android, webview, epub

I am developing ePaper android application in that i need to read text as well as image . I am able to read the text file and display it but I don't know how to display image file. I searched nearly one day about this not able to find the solution. Can any one face this problem.

Comment: Maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510721/how-to-get-the-images-of-epub-book-in-android